# AngularJS - Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/xml

Tags: json, angularjs

I am trying to load data from json. But my code is error.

**error message**

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/xml: "myJsonUrl". ionic.bundle.js:17002
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : notice:1 //notice:1 mean json
```

I use this : http://codepen.io/m_abdelfattah/pen/Gkiju

I think js source code is ok. How can I fix it?

Comment: Send correct response headers. For jsonp, it must be `text/javascript`.

Comment: @dfsq Thank you for your advice. Where I write this code?